# Accessing all input streams from an external usb audio interface with CoreAudio

Tags: c++, macos, audio, signal-processing, core-audio

I am working with CoreAudio examples to interface with various different audio interfaces. I took the CAPlayThrough example (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CAPlayThrough/Introduction/Intro.html) and have been modifying little things here and there. One of the main things that I wanted to accomplish was to access all the input streams of all the input channels from my 4 channel audio interface simultaneously during playback. In my particular setup I have a behringer uphoria 404 interface that has 4 physical input channels that I want to access simultaneously. i.e. if i have mic/instruments plugged into channel 1,2,3 and 4 in the external interface, I want to be able to hear the output from all 4 channels like you would in a DAW such as pro tools, logic, etc.

So I took the example from this documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2091/_index.html) and proceeded to create my own channel map.

So what I did was write this and set the channel map for my input AudioUnit

```
//Create channel Map
SInt32 *channelMap = NULL;
UInt32 numOfChannels = this->streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
UInt32 mapSize = numOfChannels *sizeof(SInt32);
channelMap = (SInt32 *)malloc(mapSize);

for(UInt32 i=0;i<numOfChannels;i++)
{
    channelMap[i]=-1;
}
channelMap[0] = 0;
channelMap[1] = 1;
channelMap[2] = 0;
channelMap[3] = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty(mInputUnit,
                     kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                     1,
                     channelMap,
                     mapSize);
free(channelMap);
```

The results were I could only access the data from channel 1 and 2 from my interface. However when I changed the channel map to this:

```
channelMap[0] = 2;
channelMap[1] = 3;
```

I can access data from channel 3 and 4 from my audio interface, but not channel 1 and 2.

So I figured I would have to set the channel map for my output AudioUnit. So I set the channel map to my output AudioUnit:

```
SInt32 *channelMap = NULL;
UInt32 numOfChannels = this->streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
UInt32 mapSize = numOfChannels *sizeof(SInt32);
channelMap = (SInt32 *)malloc(mapSize);

for(UInt32 i=0;i<numOfChannels;i++)
{
    channelMap[i]=-1;
}
channelMap[0] = 0;
channelMap[1] = 1;
channelMap[2] = 0;
channelMap[3] = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty(this->outputUnit,
                     kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                     1,
                     channelMap,
                     mapSize);
free(channelMap);
```

Still the same results.

Is setting the channel map the correct way of going about this? I've combed through Apple's documentation website and tried to look at their documentation, but could not find anything more helpful than the article posted above.

UPDATE:

These are some of the things that I have tried so far besides modifying the channel maps:

1. I thought that maybe each physical input on my 4 channel interface needed an AudioUnit to represent it and choose which channel to get the input stream from with the channel map. But when setting up multiple AudioUnit for the input, the the last AudioUnit being set ended up acting as the default input. Further more, the AUGraph only allowed me to add 1 output node.
2. Use the AudioUnit type `kAudioUnitSubType_StereoMixer` to combine multiple streams with multiple output render call backs. I was able to set up the render callbacks and properly link it to the stereo mixer AudioUnit, but wasn't sure how to connect the input streams to the output.

UPDATE 2:

I should've added this before. This is from the CAPlayThrough example listed above to set up the `kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat`:

```
//Get the Stream Format (Output client side)
propertySize = sizeof(asbd_dev1_in);
err = AudioUnitGetProperty(mInputUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 1, &asbd_dev1_in, &propertySize);
checkErr(err);
//printf("=====Input DEVICE stream format\n" ); 
//asbd_dev1_in.Print();

//Get the Stream Format (client side)
propertySize = sizeof(asbd);
err = AudioUnitGetProperty(mInputUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &asbd, &propertySize);       
checkErr(err);
//printf("=====current Input (Client) stream format\n");    
//asbd.Print(); 

//Get the Stream Format (Output client side)
propertySize = sizeof(asbd_dev2_out);
err = AudioUnitGetProperty(mOutputUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &asbd_dev2_out, &propertySize);
checkErr(err);
//printf("=====Output (Device) stream format\n");   
//asbd_dev2_out.Print();

//////////////////////////////////////
//Set the format of all the AUs to the input/output devices channel count
//For a simple case, you want to set this to the lower of count of the channels
//in the input device vs output device
//////////////////////////////////////
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame =((asbd_dev1_in.mChannelsPerFrame < asbd_dev2_out.mChannelsPerFrame) ?asbd_dev1_in.mChannelsPerFrame :asbd_dev2_out.mChannelsPerFrame) ;

// We must get the sample rate of the input device and set it to the stream format of AUHAL
propertySize = sizeof(Float64);
AudioObjectPropertyAddress theAddress = { kAudioDevicePropertyNominalSampleRate,
                                          kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
                                          kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster };

err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(mInputDevice.mID, &theAddress, 0, NULL, &propertySize, &rate);
checkErr(err);

asbd.mSampleRate =rate;
propertySize = sizeof(asbd);

//Set the new formats to the AUs...
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(mInputUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 1, &asbd, propertySize);
checkErr(err);  
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(mVarispeedUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Input, 0, &asbd, propertySize);
checkErr(err);
```

This is how the example sets up the both InputCall back and the output call back

InputCallBack setup:

```
OSStatus err = noErr;
AURenderCallbackStruct input;

input.inputProc = InputProc;
input.inputProcRefCon = this;

//Setup the input callback. 
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(mInputUnit, 
                          kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback, 
                          kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                          0,
                          &input, 
                          sizeof(input));
```

The input call back:

```
OSStatus CAPlayThrough::InputProc(void *inRefCon,
                                AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                AudioBufferList * ioData)
{
    OSStatus err = noErr;

CAPlayThrough *This = (CAPlayThrough *)inRefCon;
if (This->mFirstInputTime < 0.)
    This->mFirstInputTime = inTimeStamp->mSampleTime;

//Get the new audio data
err = AudioUnitRender(This->mInputUnit,
                     ioActionFlags,
                     inTimeStamp, 
                     inBusNumber,     
                     inNumberFrames, //# of frames requested
                     This->mInputBuffer);// Audio Buffer List to hold data
checkErr(err);

if(!err) {
    err = This->mBuffer->Store(This->mInputBuffer, Float64(inNumberFrames), SInt64(inTimeStamp->mSampleTime));
}   

return err;
}
```

This is how the output callback is setup:

```
output.inputProc = OutputProc;
output.inputProcRefCon = this;

err = AudioUnitSetProperty(mVarispeedUnit, 
                          kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
                          kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                          0,
                          &output, 
                          sizeof(output));
checkErr(err);
```

And this is the output proc

```
OSStatus CAPlayThrough::OutputProc(void *inRefCon,
                                 AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                 const AudioTimeStamp *TimeStamp,
                                 UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                 UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                 AudioBufferList * ioData)
{
OSStatus err = noErr;
CAPlayThrough *This = (CAPlayThrough *)inRefCon;
Float64 rate = 0.0;
AudioTimeStamp inTS, outTS;

if (This->mFirstInputTime < 0.) {
    // input hasn't run yet -> silence
    MakeBufferSilent (ioData);
    return noErr;
}

//use the varispeed playback rate to offset small discrepancies in sample rate
//first find the rate scalars of the input and output devices
err = AudioDeviceGetCurrentTime(This->mInputDevice.mID, &inTS);
// this callback may still be called a few times after the device has been stopped
if (err)
{
    MakeBufferSilent (ioData);
    return noErr;
}

err = AudioDeviceGetCurrentTime(This->mOutputDevice.mID, &outTS);
checkErr(err);

rate = inTS.mRateScalar / outTS.mRateScalar;
err = AudioUnitSetParameter(This->mVarispeedUnit,kVarispeedParam_PlaybackRate,kAudioUnitScope_Global,0, rate,0);
checkErr(err);

//get Delta between the devices and add it to the offset
if (This->mFirstOutputTime < 0.) {
    This->mFirstOutputTime = TimeStamp->mSampleTime;
    Float64 delta = (This->mFirstInputTime - This->mFirstOutputTime);
    This->ComputeThruOffset();   
    //changed: 3865519 11/10/04
    if (delta < 0.0)
        This->mInToOutSampleOffset -= delta;
    else
        This->mInToOutSampleOffset = -delta + This->mInToOutSampleOffset;

    MakeBufferSilent (ioData);
    return noErr;
}

//copy the data from the buffers    
err = This->mBuffer->Fetch(ioData, inNumberFrames, SInt64(TimeStamp->mSampleTime - This->mInToOutSampleOffset));    
if(err != kCARingBufferError_OK)
{
    MakeBufferSilent (ioData);
    SInt64 bufferStartTime, bufferEndTime;
    This->mBuffer->GetTimeBounds(bufferStartTime, bufferEndTime);
    This->mInToOutSampleOffset = TimeStamp->mSampleTime - bufferStartTime;
}

return noErr;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're setting your `kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat`?  How do you know you're not getting all channels? Are you setting a `kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback` and you've seen they're not there in the callback? I'd check the audio unit in isolation, in case some part of the graph is eating your extra channels.

Comment: Hey @rhythic fistman i added the snippets of code from the CAPlayThrough example.

Comment: How did this go? I'm looking at `CAPlayThrough` right now. I bet I could test your setup with two aggregate audio devices setup in `Audio MIDI Setup.app` (I don't have any > 2 channel input devices sadly)